# Insert pagination links into DOM dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, pagination

I'm currently working on creating a simple, dynamic inline pagination using `div`s and links. I've been stumped on this code for hours, trying to figure out how to create the pagination links depending on how many `.thumbnailPage` divs there currently are.

I'd like to be able to insert a div beneath the `.newsflash` div that contains the links to show the `.thumbnailPage` divs.

JavaScript:

```
/*----- Wraps .bite divs in separate, numbered .thumbnailPage divs -----*/
var addnumber = 0;
$('#newsflash .bite').each(function(i) {
    if( i % 6 == 0 ) {
        $(this).nextAll()
               .andSelf()
               .slice(0,6)
               .wrapAll('<div id="thumbnailPage'+ (++addnumber) +'content"></div>');
    }
});

/*----- Hides .thumbnailPage divs -----*/
$('#newsflash').children().hide();

/*----- Hopefully a code to insert pagination links here, depending on number of .thumbnailPages -----*/

/*----- Function for .thumbnailPage links -----*/
$('#pagewrapper a').click(function () {

    var chosen1 = this.id;
    var divIdToShow = chosen1 + 'content';

    $('#newsflash').children('div').each(function (i) {
        var currentDiv = $(this);
        if (this.id == divIdToShow) {
            if (currentDiv.not(':visible')) {
                currentDiv.show();
            }
        } else {
            currentDiv.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="newsflash" id="newsflash">
    <div id="thumbnailPage1content">...</div>
    <div id="thumbnailPage2content">...</div>
    <div id="thumbnailPage3content">...</div>

    <!--- Hopefully insert this pagewrapper div here depending on how many thumbnailPages --->
    <div id="pagewrapper">
        <a id="thumbnailPage1">1</a>
        <a id="thumbnailPage2">2</a>
        <a id="thumbnailPage3">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: @undefined: Sorry for the confusion; I've made an edit. :)